# how to display element from list once during mapping over array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

I have short question. I am mapping twice over nested array, and I would like to display values only once. Is it possible? I am working with react. For better explain my case I add code:

```
render(){
    const list =
     this.props.terms.map((term,index)=>(
       <p key={index}>{term}</p>
     )
   )
   const arrays = this.props.recipes.map(recipe=>recipe.c.map(comp=>comp.co));
   const filtered = arrays.map(array=>array.filter(el => this.props.terms.includes(el)))
   console.log(filtered);
        return (
         <div>
            <input type="text"
              onChange={(event)=>this.onChangeHandler(event.target.value)}
            />
            <button
              onClick={()=>this.props.addTermToCompare(this.state.term)}>
              Search ingredients
            </button>
          <div>
               <p>Searched ingredients:</p>
               <div>
                {list}
               </div>
          </div>
            <div>
            What you can cook from ingredients above:
              **{filtered.map(one=> one ?
              <div>
                {this.props.recipes.map(recipe=>recipe.c.map((comp,index)=>comp.co == one ?
                  <div>
                    {recipe.re}
                  </div>
                  : null
                ))}
              </div>
               : null )
              }**

            </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

So in the example above I want to display recipe.re only one time(not looping with another map).

Comment: What us `filtered` and what is `recipes` ? Whats your current output and what do you wanna get instead?

Comment: Filtered returnes same values  from two arrays. Recipe is mapped recipes. Output is lopped becose of mapping filtered and recipes.

Comment: Recipes.c is nested array of objects.

Comment: We need code. Please [edit] your question and provide some sample data, have a look at [mcve]

Comment: With all my respect, but my question was simple: could I display a recipe.re only one time when I map twice over nested array. I try to do something in <div>{recipe.re}</div> but even if I create array from it and filter it, it shows few times a result. So I wonder if it`s possible at all in this form.